# Trying to get bytes in ASCII format in sniff function in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am having a problem where I can't get the raw bytes in ascii format when using the sniff() function in scapy.
Example, i have this function:

`a = sniff(filter="tcp port 5900",iface="eth0", prn=lambda x: x.show(), count=20)`

And the output of `a.summary()` of one of the packets:

[image: image1]

I would like the raw output to be in ascii format, since when I open the pcap file in Wireshark, it normally comes in ascii format.
For example:

[image: image2]

I would like the output of the sniff function to come in ascii format just like in wireshark. Is it possible?

I tried several parameters in the documentation but was unsuccessful. I was hoping to be able to extract this data in ASCII format like in wireshark using the sniff function.

Comment: Please post code/text instead of images.

Comment: the code is just the sniff function. The images are the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the behavior of the `show` method of the `Packet` class (see [source code](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/341b285cea0f17ed7e52a01b5cc59bd62d5e6ec9/scapy/packet.py#L1480)). It boils down to patch `_show_or_dump`. You should identify values of type `bytes` and convert them to `hex` with `fvalue.hex()`:

```
from scapy.all import sniff
from scapy.packet import *
from unittest.mock import patch

def show_or_dump_hex(self,
                dump=False,  # type: bool
                indent=3,  # type: int
                lvl="",  # type: str
                label_lvl="",  # type: str
                first_call=True  # type: bool
                ):
    # type: (...) -> Optional[str]
    """
    Internal method that shows or dumps a hierarchical view of a packet.
    Called by show.

    :param dump: determine if it prints or returns the string value
    :param int indent: the size of indentation for each layer
    :param str lvl: additional information about the layer lvl
    :param str label_lvl: additional information about the layer fields
    :param first_call: determine if the current function is the first
    :return: return a hierarchical view if dump, else print it
    """

    if dump:
        from scapy.themes import AnsiColorTheme
        ct = AnsiColorTheme()  # No color for dump output
    else:
        ct = conf.color_theme
    s = "%s%s %s %s \n" % (label_lvl,
                        ct.punct("###["),
                        ct.layer_name(self.name),
                        ct.punct("]###"))
    for f in self.fields_desc:
        if isinstance(f, ConditionalField) and not f._evalcond(self):
            continue
        if isinstance(f, Emph) or f in conf.emph:
            ncol = ct.emph_field_name
            vcol = ct.emph_field_value
        else:
            ncol = ct.field_name
            vcol = ct.field_value
        fvalue = self.getfieldval(f.name)
        if isinstance(fvalue, Packet) or (f.islist and f.holds_packets and isinstance(fvalue, list)):  # noqa: E501
            pad = max(0, 10 - len(f.name)) * " "
            s += "%s  \\%s%s\\\n" % (label_lvl + lvl, ncol(f.name), pad)
            fvalue_gen = SetGen(
                fvalue,
                _iterpacket=0
            )  # type: SetGen[Packet]
            for fvalue in fvalue_gen:
                s += fvalue._show_or_dump(dump=dump, indent=indent, label_lvl=label_lvl + lvl + "   |", first_call=False)  # noqa: E501
        else:
            pad = max(0, 10 - len(f.name)) * " "
            begn = "%s  %s%s%s " % (label_lvl + lvl,
                                    ncol(f.name),
                                    pad,
                                    ct.punct("="),)
            if isinstance(fvalue, bytes):   # this is where we check if the value is of type bytes
                reprval = fvalue.hex()
            else:
                reprval = f.i2repr(self, fvalue)
            if isinstance(reprval, str):
                reprval = reprval.replace("\n", "\n" + " " * (len(label_lvl) +  # noqa: E501
                                                            len(lvl) +
                                                            len(f.name) +
                                                            4))
            s += "%s%s\n" % (begn, vcol(reprval))
    if self.payload:
        s += self.payload._show_or_dump(  # type: ignore
            dump=dump,
            indent=indent,
            lvl=lvl + (" " * indent * self.show_indent),
            label_lvl=label_lvl,
            first_call=False
        )

    if first_call and not dump:
        print(s)
        return None
    else:
        return s

with patch.object(Packet, '_show_or_dump', show_or_dump_hex):
    a = sniff(iface="eth0", prn=lambda x: x.show(), count=20)
```

Output sample:

```
###[ TCP ]###
        sport     = 54346
        dport     = 8080
        seq       = 3963954686
        ack       = 1203731561
        dataofs   = 5
        reserved  = 0
        flags     = PA
        window    = 1026
        chksum    = 0x5518
        urgptr    = 0
        options   = []
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = 160303002510000021204b4a9d45e1716324cfe25d7535735aadec14fde479f6a238ac2aa83fb24e0b6614030300010116030300280000000000000000589efd0d4da6de55e816d04f0055e664628e1f11a43ad68a1fb8a45ff26af4ef
```

Edit: this can be done in a less verbose way by patching `_StrField.i2repr()` ([source code](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/341b285cea0f17ed7e52a01b5cc59bd62d5e6ec9/scapy/fields.py#L1430)):

```
from scapy.all import sniff
from scapy.fields import _StrField
from unittest.mock import patch

def i2repr_hex(self, pkt, x):
        # type: (Optional[Packet], I) -> str
        if isinstance(x, bytes):
            return x.hex()
        return super(_StrField, self).i2repr(pkt, x)

with patch.object(_StrField, 'i2repr', i2repr_hex):
    a = sniff(iface="eth0", prn=lambda x: x.show(), count=20)
```